# Loading shows in background after completion of downloading Imgage in android

Tags: android, android-layout, lazy-loading

As you can identify from screen shot that After completing downloading of image it shows progress `dialog` is still loading in background. I have implemented `Async` Task in my project to Load images from server and display. I have also put `m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();` too. In HDPI it doesn't shows while in `LDPI` and `MDPI` it shows. I have put One blank frame as a first layer then loading then Downloaded image. Any solution?
[image: You can see in image background there is still loading]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me and the screenshots are very small, please give some more details.

May be View.SetVisibility(View.Invisible) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Keep `m.ProgressDialog.dismiss();` inside the onPostExecute method:

```
onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    m.ProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, one of my collegue had taken Dynamic progressbar in that code, i have just decrease the size of that progressbar. so it automatically comes behind the image. so not able to see that bar.